# SSMS is fast than Provider=SQLNCLI.1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, vbscript, ssms, adodb

I am using SQL native client in VB script to execute a query.
Connection string is

```
ConCI.Open("Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=" & CIDBName & ";Data Source=" & CIServerName)
```

Query is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM statementheader WITH (nolock)
WHERE statementdate >=
(
    SELECT procdayend-1 
    FROM
    ARSystemAccounts
) 
AND currentbalance <= 0 
AND dateoftotaldue IS NOT NULL
AND systemstatus <> 14
```

SSMS takes 50 to 60 seconds to execute this query but VB script takes ages.
Why is it so  and what should I do ?

Comment: Search. Read. http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: I had gone through the link but its quite lengthy and does not practically tell me the solution

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a "press this button" solution.

Comment: Will SET ARITHABORT ON work ?